# How to import a python 2.7 file into a python 3.5 file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.5

Currently, our group is working on building an GUI for our platform. We used pyqt5 so that we make our code python 3.5. However, when we want to add other group's function to our code, it turns out that they are using some packages that only supported in python 2.7.

So my question is, how can we import their files into our file, so that both can work properly?

Comment: well, you can't import 2.7 specific packages in 3.5. You have to choose (and choose 3.5). Some porting is needed here. Which packages can't you use in 3.5?

Comment: I'd start by punching them for using 2.7 for a new project. There is no easy way to do it. You'll have to change something.

Comment: So is there any way to add their code into ours in this case?

Comment: So at least one group has to change their version?

Comment: You'll need to port it.

Comment: @WilliamShu Yea, and it should be the group that used 2.7.

Comment: @SuperStew is there a good way to automatically change the code from pyqt5 to pyqt4？

Comment: @WilliamShu unfortunately i don't think there is. There is quite a bit of difference between the two. You could try by simply changing 5 to 4 everywhere, and dealing with the errors as they come up, but that could be a long and painful process.